# Change Wallpaper with AMD EyeFinity

Tags: timer, wallpaper

Is it possible to set a different wallpaper for each monitor? I want to code a little tool for automatically changing the wallpaper after an amount of time. I have three monitors and I wanted to use a wallpaper with a dimension of 5760x1080. The program should automatically recognize the actual monitor configuration and split the desired wallpaper(s) to three images in the correct order. I also want the possibility to use three different wallpapers on my monitor constellation. The preferred language is C#. Thanks for your help!

Regards
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes with DisplayFusion.
                                          .